# Can a switch block a physical port?

Tags: switch, mac-address

I live in a dorm where our wing has about 15 rooms, each with a physical LAN port from a wing switch, which is our link to the internet.

To mess with the subnet, I spoofed my MAC to my friend's MAC address. I've done this before, and it just leads to loss of packets at worst, but this time it lead to serious consequences.

My friend's LAN port is not responding at all. It is powered up, but all packets sent up are dropped. Even DHCP requests are not acked. Put a static IP and Broadcast ARPs are dropped too.

Can the switch do this, ban a physical port? Or there is some other problem I am unaware of? How to fix this?

Comment: Yes, there are various switch technologies that can disable a port until it is re-enabled, but a network administrator.  Without specifics on the switch model, code version, and configuration we can't help you, which is why this sort of question is off-topic on this forum. Please see the Help Center for which types of questions are allowed, and which types are not allowed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you *didn't physically connect* another machine to the port where your friend is connected, but just spoofed his Mac, then it's possible that somewhere along the route a switch saw what it calls a **'mac-flap'** .

> Basically, it learnt a Mac through one port, and now it sees the same Mac on another port. The switch can be set to do several things as a result of this, from err-disabling to suspending l2 learning for a brief period

As the previous commenter stated, find the model of switch, and then its capabilities.

Comment: It could also be port security to prevent someone from hooking up a switch or WAP in their dorm. The switch might think that it has multiple MACs on one port within a certain timeout period and might have disabled the port for that reason.

Comment: Do you has spoke with the person on charge at the management of switches, because maybe, he had configured with some kind of port security against MAC-ADDRESS-FLAPPING, switches can do that, and if it detected a mac address learned by 2 ports, bang!!!, the switch will block one of then, or do something configured, until the administrator check de issue. This is a sacurity measure against loops and another networks troubles.

Comment: We cut the power to the switch for a while, essentially restarting it. That worked.